# Fetching multiple records from multiple tables using stored procedure in Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
create procedure GetCityArea
as
begin
    select * from CityMaster;
    select * from Area;
End
```

This is my stored procedure `GetCityArea` which returns multiple record.

My exact problem is I am getting multiple record from the stored procedure, and I want to show this result in single view as separate tables. I am new in ASP.NET MVC and I want to solve this problem using Entity Framework. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using ObjectContext and the Translate method.

The gory details are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx

Comment: Very interesting - thank you, Erik, for pointing that out! Doesn't look very "polished" and EF like - but at least it can be done.

Comment: No, that is why I used the word "gory"

Comment: Hey Erik could you help me little more.In this stored procedure only two select statement is there what if it contains more than two statement.

Comment: Hey Erik actually my problem is I have stored procedure which contains 7 to 8 select statement but  I want to  fetch only 5 result set from different table .this means in my controller i want to set limit to record set which is coming from stored procedure and another problem is in above stored procedure i know i am getting city records and area records so to display this record i have created two different list.what if i don't know what record set I am getting then how to display this different record set to my view.

Comment: You need to change your stored procedure to be predictable!